# Get all GMSMarker from mapview and remove all marker without using mapview.clear()

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker, gmsmapview

I have drawn path with marker in google map. So the path is static but marker needs to change their positions. How can I remove all markers without using `mapview.clear()`, because it will clear my path also from the map.

Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you will have to keep all markers in an array(eg. `allMarkers`). Then,

```
for marker in allMarkers {
    marker.map  = nil
}
```